# pthreads program doesn't behave well

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm trying to make a simple program using pthreads, want to make 6 threads and pass index to all of them. here's the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define num_students 6

void thread_starter();

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1[num_students];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<num_students; i++) {
        int q = i;
        pthread_create(&thread1[i], NULL, (void *) &thread_starter, (void *)&q);
        }
    sleep(1);
}


void thread_starter(void* a) {
    printf("Thread %i \n", *((int*)a));
}
```

And the output:

```
Thread 2
Thread 3 
Thread 2 
Thread 4 
Thread 5 
Thread 5
```

why do they have commmon names? what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a stack address from the main thread into all the child threads.  There is no guarantee when these threads will be scheduled so you have no way of knowing whether the main thread will have updated its stack variable by the time each child gets around to reading it.

To avoid this, you need to allocate memory for the data being passed to each thread.

The easiest way to do this in your example is to use another automatic variable to store the data being passed to the new threads

```
void thread_starter(void* a);
int main() {
    pthread_t thread1[num_students];
    int thread_data[num_students];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<num_students; i++) {
        thread_data[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&thread1[i], NULL, thread_starter, &thread_data[i]);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Note also that you can avoid having to cast `thread_starter` if you give it the correct signature in your forward declaration.

For more complex programs you may need to dynamically allocate memory for each thread instead, passing ownership of that memory to the new threads.

```
int main() {
    pthread_t thread1[num_students];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<num_students; i++) {
        int* data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
        *data = i;
        pthread_create(&thread1[i], NULL, thread_starter, data);
    }
    sleep(1);
}

void thread_starter(void* a) {
    printf("Thread %i \n", *((int*)a));
    free(a);
}
```

Finally, using `sleep(1)` isn't a very rigorous way of ensuring that all your threads will be run.  It'd be better to use [pthread_join](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) instead

```
for(i = 0; i<num_students; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread1[i], NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` is not the correct tool to wait for spawned threads, use `pthread_join` for this.

Your `main` function terminating is equivalent to calling `exit` for the whole program and killing all the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Try This for Variation

```
void thread_starter(void* a) {
// Put a sleep(1) Here and see you will get even bizarre results
printf("Thread %i \n", *((int*)a));
}
```

Ok the problem here is of course

**the race condition**  at this point here

```
int q = i;
pthread_create(&thread1[i], NULL, (void *) &thread_starter, (void *)&q);
```

lets say the first thread is created and the value at q is 0

now assume that before executing the statement Here

```
printf("Thread %i \n", *((int*)a));
```

if the main thread loops further and executes this statement here

```
int q = i;
```

again, then the q value changes (because its a reference) hence the problem

well one way to avoid this is to copy this reference variable in a local variable in thread routine also use mutex.

Sorry I was on a Hurry some more tips from my side

```
#define num_students 6
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  // A Global Mutex
```

Will aquire a lock Here

```
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
    printf("\n Got Mutex %d\n", i);
    int q = i;
    pthread_create(&thread1[i], NULL, (void *) &thread_starter, (void *)&q);
```

and will release the lock Here in child Routine

```
int i = *((int*)a);
sleep(1);
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
printf("Thread %i \n", i);
```

P.S - Remove un necessary Prints and Sleeps where ever not applicable

Comment: How does copying `a` inside `thread_starter` help?  Its value may already have been changed.  If this is where you recommend use of a mutex, your answer could do with some clarification.